# Number of continuous weeks by group

Tags: r, data.table

How do I find number of continuous weeks by group but counted from the max date in the dataset?

Say I have this dataframe:

```
  id       Week
1   A  2/06/2019
2   A 26/05/2019
3   A 19/05/2019
4   A 12/05/2019
5   A  5/05/2019
6   B  2/06/2019
7   B 26/05/2019
8   B 12/05/2019
9   B  5/05/2019
10  C 26/05/2019
11  C 19/05/2019
12  C 12/05/2019
13  D  2/06/2019
14  D 26/05/2019
15  D 19/05/2019
16  E  2/06/2019
17  E 19/05/2019
18  E 12/05/2019
19  E  5/05/2019
```

My desired output is:

```
id count
1:  A     5
2:  B     2
3:  D     3
4:  E     1
```

I am currently converting dates into factor to get ordered number and checking against the reference number created based on the number of rows in each group.

```
library(data.table)
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                      2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
                                    .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
                     Week = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L), 
                                      .Label = c("12/05/2019", "19/05/2019", "2/06/2019", "26/05/2019", "5/05/2019"), class = "factor")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, Week_no := as.factor(as.Date(Week, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))]
dt[, Week_no := factor(Week_no)]
dt[, Week_no := as.numeric(Week_no)]

max_no <- max(dt$Week_no)
dt[, Week_ref := max_no:(max_no - .N + 1), by = "id"]
dt[, Week_diff := Week_no - Week_ref]
dt[Week_diff == 0, list(count = .N), by = "id"]
```

Comment: `lubridate::week` may be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
dt <- dt[, Week := as.Date(Week, format = "%d/%m/%Y")]
ids_having_max <- dt[.(max(Week)), id, on = "Week"]
dt <- dt[.(ids_having_max), on = "id"
         ][order(-Week), .(count = sum(rleid(c(-7L, diff(Week))) == 1)), by = "id"]
```

Breaking it into steps:

We leave `Week` as a date because it can already be compared,
and you can subtract dates to get time differences.

We then get all the `id`s that contain the maximum date in the whole table.
This is using [secondary indices](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html).

We use secondary indices again to filter out those `id`s that were *not* part of the previous result
(the `dt[.(ids_having_max), on = "id"` part).

The last frame is tricky.
We group by `id` and make sure that rows are ordered by `Week` in descending order.
Then the logic is as follows.

When you have contiguous weeks,
`diff(Week)` is always -7 with the chosen sorting.
Computing `diff` returns a shorter vector because the first result is computed by subtracting the first input element from the second,
so we prepend a -7 to make sure that it is the first element in the input to `rleid`.

With `rleid` we assign a 1 to the first -7 and keep the 1 until we see something different from -7.
Something different means weeks stopped being contiguous.
The `sum(rleid(c(-7L, diff(Week))) == 1)` will simply return how many rows had a `rleid` equal to 1.

Example of the last part for `B`:

- Differences: `-7, -14, -7`
- After prepending -7: `-7, -7, -14, -7`
- After `rleid`: `1, 1, 2, 3`
- From the previous, two had a `rleid == 1`

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for `dplyr` solution, but I presume a similar approach can be achieved more concisely with `data.table`.

```
library(dplyr)
df$Week = lubridate::dmy(df$Week)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, Week) %>%
  # Assign group to each new streak
  mutate(new_streak = cumsum(Week != lag(Week, default = 0) + 7)) %>%
  add_count(id, new_streak) %>%
  slice(n()) # Only keep last week
```

Comment: Thanks for the `dplyr` solution, always good to find out alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

So I would suggest converting the format of the data column to show week number `"%W"` as follows

```
dt[, Week_no := format(as.Date(Week, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),"%W")]
```

Then find the amount of unique week numbers for each `id` value

```
dt[,(length(unique(Week_no))),by="id"]
```

**FULL DISCLOSURE**

I realise that when I run this I get a different table than you present, as R counts the week by the week # for the given year.

If this doesnt answer your question just let me know and I can try to update

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work as the question is more around how to find number of continuous weeks not unique weeks.